# How to create calculated field based on another time series

Tags: tableau-api

I have a set of prices as data source for given timeseries and I would like to create a calculated field by combining two prices for each date: i.e., 
 `Price A *5 - Price B`.

Data source:

```
Date    Product Price
01.01.2018  A   10
01.01.2018  B   15
02.01.2018  A   20
02.01.2018  B   30
03.01.2018  A   10
03.01.2018  B   30
```

I don't know how to write the formula correctly for the Calculated field.

What I expect is to build the following table:

```
Date    A   B   Combined Price (A *5 - B)
01.01.2018  10  15  35
02.01.2018  20  30  70
03.01.2018  10  30  20
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Mohfooj can be found in Tableau forum here: https://community.tableau.com/message/900181#900181

Comment: Hi Jack M, Not a bad link (and links are fine) but you should provide your own solution to your post. If you realize that you do not want to do that, perhaps just add a link to your original post stating the links helpfulness.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, will definetely do the next time, as this is my first post - not quite there yet, neither with questions nor with answers.